# Javascript Cell Filling

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I'm trying to fill an HTML table with some values from my JS code.
The first few lines work, but my function doesn't.

Does anyone know why? I've included my code below.

```js
function set(id,num) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = num;
}
var num1 = set("1.4", 55); //ok
var num2 = set("1.6", 56); //ok
var num3 = set("1.12", 57); //ok

function addition() { //notok
    //var n1 = document.getElementById("1.4").innerHTML;
    //var n2 = document.getElementById("1.6").innerHTML;
    //var n3 = document.getElementById("1.12").innerHTML;
    //document.getElementById("1.14").innerHTML = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2) + parseInt(n3);
    document.getElementById("1.14").innerHTML = 55 + 56 + 57;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

table {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid black 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

td, th {
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.theader {
    background-color: rgb(254, 102, 0);
}

th:first-child{
    border-top: none;
}

td {
    text-align:center;
}



td:first-child, th:first-child {
     font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

  tr { background-color: white}
  .change { background-color: black; color:white }
  .normal { background-color: white }
  .notchange{ background-color: white }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>        
    <table>
<tr class="normal" onmouseover="this.className='change'" onmouseout="this.className='notchange'">
  <td>Row1</td>
  <td id="1.1">11</td>
  <td id="1.2">11</td>
  <td id="1.3">12</td>
  <td id="1.4"></td>
  <td id="1.5">14</td>
  <td id="1.6"></td>
  <td id="1.7">16</td>
  <td id="1.8">17</td>
  <td id="1.9">18</td>
  <td id="1.10">19</td>
  <td id="1.11">20</td>
  <td id="1.12"></td>
  <td id="1.13">22</td>
  <td id="1.14"></td>
</tr>
...........
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyJavaScript1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am writing just a table with JS, ("1.4","1.6","1.12") cells filling properly but i can not fill the cell "1.14".

Comment: What are those "cells"? if `<td>` or  `<th>` then those have no `value` attribute... Could use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: So commented lines in addition() is ok you said, right?

Comment: we need to see your HTML markup. And please copy/paste actual code into the question in future, not screenshots.

Comment: you never call the addition() function anywhere, so the code to set the 1.14 cell never runs. The rest of them just run when the page loads, because they're not wrapped in another function. Is the "addition()" function supposed to be triggered by some event, perhaps?

Comment: oh you are right ,sorry it is my mistake, i deleted the code:  addition(); Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually [invoke the function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) so it doesn't run.

Change your code to look like this:

```
function set(id,num) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = num;
}
var num1 = set("1.4", 55); //ok
var num2 = set("1.6", 56); //ok
var num3 = set("1.12", 57); //ok

function addition() { //notok
    document.getElementById("1.14").innerHTML = 55 + 56 + 57;
}

// added this line:
addition();
```

I added the last line (and removed commented lines) which will invoke the method (thus running the code inside) and I moved the function to the top of the file. While not neccessary to move the function thanks to [function hoisting](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting) I feel it's good practice to declare a function before invoking it.

**Additional note**

You're assigning the result of the set function to a variable with the following line:

```
var num1 = set("1.4", 55); //ok
```

You don't *have* to do this. You can just call set("1.4", 55).

**======== OLD ANSWER BELOW ==========**

> You're using `getElementById` and `.valueOf` wrong. `getElementById`
>   refers to a HTML element. For example:
>
> `getElementById("cell1")` would pick the element which looks like:
>
> `<td id="cell1"></td>`
>
> **.valueOf** returns the primitive value of a String object, for example:
>
> ```
> var str = "Hello World!";
> var res = str.valueOf(); 
> console.log(res); // prints: Hello World!
> ```
>
> So assuming your html looks like this:
>
> ```
> <table>
>     <tr>
>         <td id="cell1"></td>
>         <td id="cell2"></td>
>         <td id="cell3"></td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
> ```
>
> The Javascript code to fill the cell's would look something like
>   this::
>
> ```
> document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = "1.4";
> document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML = "1.6";
> document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML = "1.12";
> ```

Comment: I'm confused, where does valueOf appear in the OP's code?

Comment: It appears the OP has significantly changed his question since I answered. The original question included a picture where we could see the OP trying to use either "value" or "valueOf" instead of .innerHTML

Comment: ah ok that makes sense

Comment: After your reply, i changed my post from screenshots to snippet with @ADyson notice. Thank you.

Comment: @tserdas seems like you also changed the actual content of the code significantly as well?

Comment: @tserdas, I removed the comments to better represent the changes. I only added the last line, add that and your code will work.

Comment: @ADyson no i just deleted other rows and value attribute. because i learn the usage of value attribute with first comment from Usagi.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addition() { //OK
    var n1 = document.getElementById("1.4").innerHTML;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("1.6").innerHTML;
    var n3 = document.getElementById("1.12").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("1.14").innerHTML = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2) + parseInt(n3);
}
addition();
```

And it works. My fault. I deleted to function call and forget to write again.